# Shell script using function to display system information sending errors

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

I'm trying to write a script to keep track of my system information. I want to use "function" in the script and just call the functions out. I'm having trouble with the commands working in the function. Obviously they are written incorrectly.

```
#!/bin/bash

#function definition

function report_system_uptime()
{
echo $(($uptime))
}
function report_drive_space()
{
echo $(($df))
}
function report_home_space()
{
echo $(($du /home/* | sort -nr))
}

#Call the function
report_system_uptime
report_drive_space
report_home_space
```

Comment: Why so complicated? You can just call the binaries, like `uptime`, `du /home`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the command. There's no need to echo them.

Example:

```
echo $(df -h)
```

Just call:

```
df -h
```

Another thing. Don't use $((..)). This is used to math in bash:

```
$ echo $((1+1))
2
$ echo $((df -h))
0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my errors. I didn't realize $((...)) was exclusively for math. So much to remember when writing a shell script. I guess I over analyze it.

Comment: No problem... We live, we learn :)